# MySql - select of 10 best results for every user

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql TABLE with final results of every round in game. In every round each user have different score like in normal games. User can play every round only once, so combination (`idRound`,`idUser`) will be unique.

Table look like this:

```
id: INT
idRound: INT, //id of round
idUser: INT, //id of user
score: INT // final score for that round
```

I want to have a list of best players.
**How we decide who is best?**

Every player will be compared by his best 10 score in rounds. So if he played 20 rounds (every round have its own score) only 10 his best round(highest score) will be counted and players will be ordered `DESC` by this `SUM(score)`.

Can you please help me with this SELECT?

Thank you

Comment: Tim is correct. Try to provide your code as well next time onwards.

Comment: Hi, i tried but i have problem with how to select max 10 rows for every user. For one user is not problem to make a select, but i need for all users.

Comment: @user3283649, can you please try the code I provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can proceed by doing something like this:

```
SET @intRounds:=1;
SET @intPrevUser:=-1;

SELECT idUser, idRound, rank FROM
(

    SELECT *, IF(@intPrevUser = game.idUser, @intRounds := @intRounds+1, @intRounds := 1) AS rank, @intPrevUser := game.idUser
    FROM game
    ORDER BY idUser, score DESC
    
) AS ranked_table
WHERE ranked_table.rank <=10
```

Rank each score of the user and then pickup only the desired ones.

Comment: Hi, i tried it and IT WORKS!. I added GROUP BY idUser and SUM(score) and ORDER BY that SUM. Thank you :)

Comment: Don't forget to accept this as answer if this worked. Many thanks!